# Where can I find easy to understand instructions for real world applicable inkjet printed electronics

Tags: printed

To explain what I'm trying to do a bit more, here is an overview of my ideas in this case.

As far as I understand so far, it's technically possible to create complete PCBs including chips, memory and screens with inkjet and or 3d printing and the right inks. Graphene seems to be a non toxic wonder material for this.

I am not an electrical engineer or a skilled programmer so my understanding of the limitations here is very basic.

**The most promising examples I have found are these here:**

print a working paper computer
https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22029374-500-print-a-working-paper-computer-on-an-80-inkjet/

printed 8-bit microprocessor:
https://electronics360.globalspec.com/article/4824/8-bit-microprocessor-opens-path-to-organic-iot

Printed paper memory
https://www.nanowerk.com/spotlight/spotid=36722.php

Printed tft Screens
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qg5BXH1mPs

I have been trying in my spare time to find simple DIY instructions so that I can start experimenting with printing usable electronics at myself.

By this I mean complete circuits including the microprocessing units. 
I love sites like Instructables for DIY things like this, but the best example I found there was an inkjet printed circuit with no processing capabilities. http://www.instructables.com/id/Print-Conductive-Circuits-With-An-Inkjet-Printer/

I know companies like PragmatIC are already quite advanced in this department. They make RFID tags, printed displays NFC, powered devices.

The instructions I have found on this topic are all very technical research papers that are mostly beyond my understanding.

**I need the "How to make an inkjet printed computer - For dummies" Version.**

Any links pointing to simple DIY tutorials  would be greatly appreciated. With all the amazing posibillities in this field I imagine there must be a large community like this somewhere that I have not been able to find yet.

If further clarification is wanted please let me know and I will try to explain what I'm looking for better.

**Thank you for taking the time to read this.** 
I hope this is not too off topic for the site

---

Thanks to all the answers I am now realizing that none of these examples actually have inkjet printed processors.

Thank you all for pointing that out. I see my question should be about how to print transistors/processors.

Printed transistors apparently are possible, but as I see now the company in that paper seem to be the only ones claiming they have printed a processor and I'm not finding any further evidence yet

Comment: I don't expect you to find one. Printing conductive circuits is one thing; manufacturing active semiconductor devices is quite another.

Comment: You're looking at cutting edge technology. The only way you'll get to work with it is when it becomes more common, or when you're working at the research facility developing it, with the people developing it.

Comment: The "how to print a computer" bit was meant as a joke. However manufacturing active semiconductor devices with an off the shelf inkjet printer seems to have been a thing already for a few years. 

https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22029374-500-print-a-working-paper-computer-on-an-80-inkjet/

Comment: That article only shows printed conductors. You still need to get some actual chips/components on, which most likely weren't printed.

Comment: @user695695 they're just printing wires, like a PCB but on paper instead of fibreglass.

Comment: The article does make it sound different though.

"The moisture sensor the team has printed is meant for use on plants (see picture). It detects rainfall with one circuit and soil humidity with another, transmitting its readings via a printed Wi-Fi antenna. Hodges has printed paper wiring to connect the switch, LED and battery of a 3D-printed flashlight.

In addition, the team has shown off more complex inkjet-printed circuits, with microprocessors and memory chip connectors"

Comment: And I'd like to point out that this printed microprocessor  was made at least 4 years ago

Comment: The moisture sensor (looking at the picture) looks just like a something measuring either the resistance or capacitance between the two contacts. Nothing smart, just two wires.
A WiFi antenna is again basically just a conductor. If you actually look at the paper, it's only talking about conductors, not making the active stuff.

Comment: Thanks to all the answers I am now realizing that none of these examples actually have inkjet printed processors. Thank you all for pointing that out. I see my question should be about how to print transistors/processors.  Printed transistors  apparently are possible, but as I see now the company in that paper seem to be the only ones claiming they have printed a processor and I'm not finding any further evidence yet other than these.

https://insights.dice.com/2013/11/08/ink-jet-printing-custom-designed-micro-circuits/

Comment: It's easy to print the frame of a rifle but hard to print things like springs and firing pins. We are far from being able to print everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need the "How to make an inkjet printed computer - For dummies" Version.

It doesn't exist.

The articles you're referencing are discussing technologies which currently only exist in the laboratory. They require materials and/or equipment which are not available to hobbyists. In some cases, the materials were produced by the researchers, and are not commercially available.

Comment: I realize that now. Thank you! Instructions to printed  logic gates seems to be the next best step here.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388912/why-wont-this-diy-transistor-attempt-conduct

This is my next step for this idea.